# Android service to upload folder containing multiple files to a web server

Tags: java, android, file-upload, android-service

I am new to android.I am creating a folder on my android device that contains multiple files such as pdf,mp3,csv.....I need to write an android service which runs in background and checks if internet is available...if internet is available ,i have to upload this folder to the web server...this folder is further used by my web-app which uses java.How to upload this folder from android device to web server using android service?

Comment: Yes. Ok. Interesting. Any questions?

Comment: @greenapps how to do this using android service?

Comment: That is not `this`. This is this and this and this and this and yet this. Was that all? Nothing more?

Comment: @greenapps how to upload the given folder containing different files using a started service in android?

Comment: To much question at once. Please read a hundred pages on stackoverflow tagged android and you will find all answers. Or just google for a specific problem.

Comment: It looks to me that you should be able to upload a file. We dont even know if you know how to do that. And so you did tell nothing.

Comment: @greenapps any particular optimized approach you have in your mind for this?

Comment: Please tell YOUR approach.

Comment: @greenapps thinking of creating an inputstreamreader that reads file from device and the outputstreamwriter writes those files to given location on web server.....but i believe that won't work for jpg/image files.....so my main question is how to upload any type of file to web server that runs a java based web-app PS:i am new to android...could you please share some reference code for the same?

Comment: If you know how to upload a file then you can upload every file. Type does not matter at all. So where is your problem? I already asked you if you knew how to upload ONE file?

Comment: @greenapps please tell me how to upload any type of file?

Comment: Code for that has been posted many times on stackoverflow. I think that such code is at least posted three times here the last week. Start reading stackoverflow!

Comment: @greenapps was my approach correct?...please give link for the same

Comment: `tell me how to upload any type of file`. That is not the way it works here. You should at least show the code you use to upload a specific type of file then.

Comment: `was my approach correct?.`. That was not the description of an approch at all. And it was full of nonsense.

Comment: could you please explain me a rough approach for uploading a file?

Answer (score 0):

After checking if internet is available this  library can be invoked -
https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"